# How to prevent duplicate data insert into Gridview in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

1. I have a table view like below:

> ```
> EQP       LOT_ID        ACTIVITY            MSG                     MODIFIED_DATE     
> 001      WM31960       LOAD_LOT         Load lot success.         9/29/2020 11:11:17 AM
> 001      WM31799       UNLOAD_LOT       Unload lot success.       9/29/2020 11:10:48 AM
> 001      WM31799       LOAD_LOT         Load lot success.         9/29/2020 6:03:50 AM
> 001      WM31964       UNLOAD_LOT       Unload lot success.       9/29/2020 6:02:42 AM
> 002      WM32295       LOAD_LOT         Load lot success.         9/29/2020 11:23:22 AM
> 002      WM32344       UNLOAD_LOT       Unload lot success.       9/29/2020 11:22:54 AM
> 002      WM32344       LOAD_LOT         Load lot success          9/29/2020 8:18:18 AM
> 002      WM32314       UNLOAD_LOT       Unload lot success.       9/29/2020 8:17:55 AM
> ```

**2. I want to make this table become each EQP only got one row and I will sum the LOT_ID as below:
(Calculation) TotalLOT_ID (SUM) = if LOT_ID =WM31960 and MSG=Load lot success.**

> ```
>  EQP            TotalLOT_ID                          
>  001               2
>  002               2
> ```

3. This is my Coding but I can't get the **Gridview output** that I want.

```cs
    public void btn_ClickSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            string oradb1 = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" +
          "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = vpngprdrmstmp)(PORT = xxxx))" +
          "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
          "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
          "(SERVICE_NAME = xxxxxx)" +
           ")" +
           ");User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxx;";
    
    
            DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepickerstart.Text);
            string Date = StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    
            DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Text);
            string dt2 = EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP from RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE >= to_date('" + Date + "')AND RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE < to_date('" + dt2 + "') + 1  ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP ASC";
    
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    
           
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
                {
                    using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(dt);
    
                    }
    
                    DataTable da = new DataTable();
                    da.Columns.Add("TEST", typeof(System.String));
                   
                    foreach (DataRow sd in dt.Rows)
                    {
                         
                        
                        var EQP_ID = sd["EQP"].ToString();
           
                        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
                        {
    
                           using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MSG,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE FROM RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE >= to_date('" + Date + "')AND RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE < to_date('" + dt2 + "') + 1 AND EQP ='" + EQP_ID + "' GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MSG, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE DESC"))
                           
    
                            {
                                using (OracleDataAdapter sda1 = new OracleDataAdapter())
                                {
    
                                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd1.Connection = conn;
                                    sda1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                                    sda1.Fill(da);
                                }
                                                                            
                            }
    
                            
                            DataRow prevRow = null;
                            
    
                            foreach (DataRow sda2 in da.Rows)
                            {
    
                                var eq = sda2["EQP"].ToString();
    
                                if (prevRow != null)
                                {
                                    if ( prevRow.Field<string>("EQP") != eq)
                                    {
    
                                        var eq1= sda2["EQP"].ToString();                                    
                                        sda2["TEST"] = eq1;
                                        
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var eq2 = sda2["EQP"].ToString();
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                prevRow = sda2;
    
                            }
    
                        
                            GridView2.DataSource = da;
                            GridView2.DataBind();
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Could some give me some hint or what I could try?

1. Latest Updated code as below (Added some comment inside, hope you could understand what i mean):

   ```
    public void btn_ClickSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oradb1 = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" +
   ```

   "(AD

   ```
    DRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = vpngprdrmstmp)(PORT = 1548))" +
          "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
          "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
          "(SERVICE_NAME = rmstmpdb)" +
           ")" +
           ");User ID=OTA_VIEW;Password=0taV1ew;";


            DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepickerstart.Text);
            string Date = StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Text);
            string dt2 = EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            //Get the list of EQP use DISTINCT 
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP from RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE >= to_date('" + Date + "')AND RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE < to_date('" + dt2 + "') + 1  ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID ASC";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
                {
                    using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                    }

                    DataTable da = new DataTable();
                    da.Columns.Add("EQP", typeof(string));
                    da.Columns.Add("TotalLOT_ID", typeof(string));


                    foreach (DataRow sd in dt.Rows)
                    {

                 //Once get the EQP, then run the query with many data column.
                        var EQP_ID = sd["EQP"].ToString();


                        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
                        {

                            using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MESSAGE,LISTAGG (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY  || ': ' || RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE, ','||chr(13)||chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE) AS names,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS ( LAG(RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,1)OVER(ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE DESC)  - RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE), 'HH24:MI:SS') AS Time_Different FROM RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE >= to_date('" + Date + "')AND RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE < to_date('" + dt2 + "') + 1 AND EQP ='" + EQP_ID + "' GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MESSAGE, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE DESC"))


                            {
                                using (OracleDataAdapter sda1 = new OracleDataAdapter())
                                {

                                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd1.Connection = conn;
                                    sda1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                                    sda1.Fill(da);
                                }


               //Once get the first EQP then loop to display data in GRIDVIEW             

               foreach (DataRow sda2 in da.Rows)
                                {
                                    var eqp = sda2["EQP"].ToString();
                                    var lotid = sda2["LOT_ID"].ToString();
                                    var msg = sda2["MSG"].ToString();

                                    if (lotid.Equals(lotid) && msg.Equals("Load lot success."))
                                    {
                                        string query1 = string.Format("EQP='{0}'", eqp.Replace(@"'", "''"));
                                        var rows = da.Select(query1);

                                        if (rows.Length > 0)
                                        {
                                            var rowIndex = da.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
                                            da.Rows[rowIndex]["TotalLOT_ID"] = int.Parse(da.Rows[rowIndex]["TotalLOT_ID"].ToString()) + 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (lotid.Equals(lotid) && msg.Equals("Load lot success."))
                                            {
                                                da.Rows.Add(eqp, 1);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                GridView2.DataSource = da;
                                GridView2.DataBind();




                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   ```

(UPATED:I had change my query and my table view become like below.)

> ```
> EQP       LOT        ACTIVITY            MSG                  MODIFIED_DATE 
> 001     WM34163      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 11:11:11
> 001     WM34163      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 11:11:11
> 001     WM34163      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 11:11:11
> 001     WM34163      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 11:11:11
> 001     WM34163      CANCEL_LOT        CANCEL.                10/01/2020 12:11:11
> 001     WM34160      UNLOAD_LOT        Unload lot success.    10/01/2020 13:10:12
> 001     WM34160      UNLOAD_LOT        Unload lot success.    10/01/2020 13:10:12
> 002     WM32439      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 15:11:12
> 002     WM32439      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 15:11:12
> 002     WM32439      LOAD_LOT          Load lot success.      10/01/2020 15:11:12
> ```

( I suppose only get 1= WM34163 only and WM32439 =1 , because they are duplicated Lot_id, but now it count as 4 )
Once I run the back end code, it show as below.

> ```
> ID        Total_LOTID
> 001          4  
> 002          3
> ```

This is my latest coding. I had no idea where to apply my foreach loop(sum) to avoid get deleted.

```
foreach (DataRow sda2 in da.Rows)
     {
                            var totalsum = 0;
                            DataRow prevRow = null;
                            var eqp = sda2["EQP_ID"].ToString();
                            var lot = sda2["T"].ToString();
                            var lotid = sda2["LOT_ID"].ToString();                           
                            int sum = 0;
                         

                            foreach (DataRow sa in da.Rows)
                            {
                                if (prevRow != null)
                                {
                                    var display = prevRow["LOT_ID"].ToString();
                                    if (lotid != prevRow["LOT_ID"].ToString() && lotid.Equals("1"))
                                    {
                                        sum++;

                                    }
                                }
                                prevRow = sa;
                            }
                            totalsum = sum;
                       

                            if (lot.Equals(lot))
                              {
                                string query2 = string.Format("EQP='{0}'", eqp.Replace(@"'", "''"));
                                var rows = dx.Select(query2);

                                if (rows.Length > 0)
                                 {
                                    var rowIndex = dx.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
                                       
                                      dx.Rows[rowIndex]["TotalLOT_ID"] = totalsum;

                                 }
                                else
                                {
                                    
                                    if (lot.Equals(lot))
                                    {
                                        dx.Rows.Add(eqp, 1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: All date picker controls return a `DateTime` value, there's no need to read their display text and parse it. As for the code, it tries to do explicitly what a `DbDataAdapter` does, multiple times over. A data adapter is meant to load *all* the tables in a dataset using each table's `select` query. There's no need to use multiple loops and adapters. On the other hand, using it has been abandoned for over a decade, as it's easier to load objects and relations using an ORM like EF or NHibernate.

Comment: If you really need to use a DataAdapter, check [Loading Data in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/loading-data-into-a-dataset). That code loads 5 tables with a single adapter, a single `Fill()` and no loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void btn_ClickSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);

            }

            DataTable da = new DataTable();

            // Create another DT to store final result
            DataTable dx = new DataTable();
            dx.Columns.Add("EQP", typeof(string));
            dx.Columns.Add("TotalLOT_ID", typeof(string));

            foreach (DataRow sd in dt.Rows)
            {
                //Once get the EQP, then run the query with many data column.
                var EQP_ID = sd["EQP"].ToString();

                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MESSAGE,LISTAGG (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY  || ': ' || RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE, ','||chr(13)||chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE) AS names,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS ( LAG(RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,1)OVER(ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE DESC)  - RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE), 'HH24:MI:SS') AS Time_Different FROM RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID FULL OUTER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE >= to_date('" + Date + "')AND RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE < to_date('" + dt2 + "') + 1 AND EQP ='" + EQP_ID + "' GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.LOT_ID, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.VALUE,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ACTIVITY,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MESSAGE, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE, RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID,RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE DESC"))
                    {
                        using (OracleDataAdapter sda1 = new OracleDataAdapter())
                        {

                            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd1.Connection = conn;
                            sda1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                            sda1.Fill(da);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow sda2 in da.Rows)
                    {
                        var eqp = sda2["EQP"].ToString();
                        var lotid = sda2["LOT_ID"].ToString();
                        var msg = sda2["MSG"].ToString();

                        if (lotid.Equals("WM31960") && msg.Equals("Load lot success."))
                        {
                            string query2 = string.Format("EQP='{0}'", eqp.Replace(@"'", "''"));
                            var rows = dx.Select(query2);

                            if (rows.Length > 0)
                            {
                                var rowIndex = dx.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
                                dx.Rows[rowIndex]["TotalLOT_ID"] = int.Parse(dx.Rows[rowIndex]["TotalLOT_ID"].ToString()) + 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (lotid.Equals("WM31960") && msg.Equals("Load lot success."))
                                {
                                    dx.Rows.Add(eqp, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            GridView2.DataSource = dx;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi julanove, i tried your code but i get the empty column with many row. May i know know where i do the mistake? Thanks

Comment: Hi julanove, I already updated my latest code. and  I get the new error 'An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute'

Comment: @YYY Your code looks kinda of wrong. What's the use of second query ? You got the view data into dt but still using da for some reason ??

Comment: Hi @Julanove , first query is distinct EQP only ,and then second query is display all the data with looping.

Comment: @YYY I'm sorry but this is just so wrong to me. You put the display command in a loop so Datasource of da will be binded each time you loop with a row of dt. And ended up with the data of the last row.  Could you explain your work from begining or at least add some commend ??

Comment: Hi  @Julanove I already added the comment, hopefully you can understand what i mean. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Julanove, My process flow is like eg-> Use DISTINCT to get the EQP (001) -> (LOOP) The EQP (001) with second query to get all the column like EQP,LOT_ID,ACTIVITY and MSG -> (Loop) again to display in GRIDVIEW.

Comment: @YYY What if the first query return many rows like [001,002,003]. Then your gridview's Datasource will be reset with each record and ended up at the last record value. This command does not append the new Database into its current data. GridView2.DataSource = da; It resets it.

Comment: Hi @Julanove, you are right. I try to changing now.

Comment: @julanove code-only answers are acceptable if they are short and clear how they relate to the question and how they solve the problem. This answer is neither, and doesn't even have any comments

Comment: @YYY I just wanna help, dude. Accept or not, point up or down I don't care that much

Comment: @julanove you're harming, not helping though. SO isn't a discussion forum, an answer should. *answer* the problem. You aren't helping the original poster or anyone else that may encounter the same problem. For starters, it's not clear what's different in the answer. Worse, whatever it is, it's wrong - that's not how ADO.NET works. There's no need for loops, multiple connections or data adapters.

Comment: @julanove if you want to help, [check how data is loaded in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/loading-data-into-a-dataset). Also check [How to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in SO's Help Center

Comment: Hi @Julanove, Yes, its working now. May i know its possible to do the calculation then put in third column ? Like the final output will become EQP,TOTAL_LOTID, SUM_Calculation ?

Comment: @YYY What do you want to sum ? If it's sum of all the TOTAL_LOTID then it should be displayed outside of the gridview since it does not belong to any row.

Comment: Hi @julanove, I want to find the time different of MODIFIED_DATE column for (001) Which mean second row subtract first row, third row subtract second row and the rest, Once I get the time different in each row then I will do checking. - if (ACTIVITY==UNLOAD_LOT) then I want sum the TIME DIFFERENT between row. and display in  third column. It's possible?

Comment: @YYY It's possible, just create new column in DataTable dx and use DateTime.Subtract to calculate the time between each row and store it in the new column.

Comment: Hi @julanove, i realized  that my total_LOTID is not tally with my database, it always count the  EQP (001). first loop (001) already count one time then next  next loop(001) countinue count again. i cant find the solution. May i know where is the problem cause?

Comment: Hi @julanove, i already solved the above comment looping issue, thanks.

Comment: Hi @julanove ,i tried to use  for loop to count the LOT_ID but i not sure where should i applied that code? can you help me on this? I had updated the latest table view at above. Thanks

Comment: Hi @julanove, can you help me on this problem? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201349/how-to-sum-in-gridview-with-certain-requirement-in-c-sharp-asp-net